# How to write generic method that wait to selenium webElement

Tags: c#, selenium

So instead of write every time i want to search element this `WebDriverWait webDriverWait` and use it with `until...` i want to write generic method:

```
static IWebElement FindElement(ExpectedConditions expectedConditions, By by, int timeOut)
{
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut));
    IWebElement element =
    webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("foo")));
}
```

I want to pass this method several parameters:

```
1. ExpectedConditions. 
2. By option.
3. time out in seconds.
```

So as you can see this almost ready but how can i put this `ExpectedConditions` and the `selector` type in my method ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an extension method:

```
public static IWebElement WaitElementPresent(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeout = 10) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
        .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
}

public static IWebElement WaitElementVisible(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeout = 10) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
        .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
}

public static IWebElement Wait(this IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> condition, int timeout = 10) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).Until(condition);
}
```

Here is a few usage examples:

```
// wait for an element to be present and click it
driver.Wait(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("..."))).Click();

// wait for an element to be visible and click it
driver.Wait(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("...")), 5).Click();

// wait for an element to be present and click it
driver.WaitElementPresent(By.Id("...")).Click();

// wait for an element to be visible and click it
driver.WaitElementVisible(By.Id("...")).Click();
```

Note that an extension method must to be placed in a static class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: What is the benefits of split this into 2 methods instead of one that receive the desire ExpectedConditions ?

Comment: The method `driver.Wait` is more flexible compared to the other ones,

Comment: What about using PoolingEvery ?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: driver.Wait(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("..."))).pollingEvery(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).Click();

Comment: And what is it supposed to do? The PollingInterval is a property from the WebDriverWait instance, not a method.